# Test to find expected outcome

Tags: chi-squared-test, permutation-test, hypergeometric-distribution, gwas, empirical-likelihood

I have a list of genes and I tested if these genes are associated with a disease by using the genome-wide association summary statistics dataset. Chi-square statistics was used and after performing permutations, I could calculate the empirical P value (number of times the simulated statistic value exceeds the calculated chi-square statistics) and found the 14 genes were significantly associated with disease. I need advice if there is a way to find if these 14 genes are more than expected by chance. Can hypergeometric test be used to find if these 14 genes are more than expected by chance?

I used the UCLA calculator https://systems.crump.ucla.edu/hypergeometric/ as shown in the snapshot by assuming the values as follows

```
Number of genes in the genome-wide association summary statistics dataset = 18820

Number of genes significantly associated with disease = 416

Number of genes (from my list) to be tested= 49

Number of genes (from my list) found to be associated in the genome-wide association summary statistics dataset =14

Expected value = 49*416/18820
```

I am not sure if this is right way to do. I assume that this expected value which is 1.083 is lower than observed value which is 14. Can someone explain how this could be calculated and interpreted?

Thank you